# How to fix weird Google Script code writing cursor issue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This seems like a simple problem but I can't find where this was changed, so as I was
editing a script for google sheets I realized that I couldn't edit my code without it removing the text
 on the right of the cursor.
For example:

```
if(var i == 0){}
```

If I want to edit it and say put i + 1 this is what happens:

```
if(var i+1= 0){}
```

I cannot add spaces if I want to edit inside pre-existing code, and I can't
see where I changed it. Any references are appreciated.

Comment: This happens when you hit the "Insert" key, it toggles between inserting new text and overwriting the text following the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the window/google script editor window and re-opened it, looks to be working fine.